Getting plugin 'adb' not found without adb plugin installed
When I open Terminal it prints [oh-my-zsh] plugin 'adb' not found. I've checked ~/.zshrc, confirmed the adb plugin isn't present, and sourced it but it continues to crop up. I've also checked my omz plugins, and it isn't there, either. I even tried reinstalling the plugin & uninstalling it again but didn't have luck getting the message to stop. Rebooting also didn't help.

You can remove adb plugin from the plugin array since Zsh already has official completion built-in.
You can refer to: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/discussions/12577.
